# Строки TXT файла в многомерный массив при помощи JS

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Допустим есть у меня `*.txt` файл с таким наполнением (4 строки по 5 элементов):

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14
15,16,17,18
```

Возможно ли при помощи `JS` прочитать этот файл и сделать из него массив даного вида: `arr = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15],[16,17,18,19,20]];`?
В `PHP` делал данный маневр, но `JS` только исследую, и не все понятно пока что.  Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Реализовал через `FileReader`

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
```

JS:

```
if ( ! (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)) {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var file = evt.target.files[0];
    if (!file.type.match('text.*')) {
            return alert(file.name + " is not a valid text file.");
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
       var textToArray = reader.result.split("\n").map(function(x){return x.split(",")});
       console.log(textToArray); 
     };
 }

window.onload = function () {
 document.getElementById('file').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false); 
}
```

Результат (массив):

```
[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14],[15,16,17,18]];
```

Демо:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZKQRx?editors=1011

Comment: а как обраться к первой строке

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript не имеет доступа к файловой системе на стороне клиента. Это сделано в целях безопасности. Поэтому краткий ответ: нет, нельзя.

Посмотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21012580/5045688) вопрос.

Comment: Но ведь через HTML5 API `FileReader` можно считать файл, загруженный через input=file...... соответственно прочитать то файл можно